# React setState has one character delay

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form with a few fields created with react and an `onChange` handler:

```
<Form.Control id="user_email" required type="email" onChange={this.handleChange} name="email"/>
```

the Handler:

```
handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    })
}
```

When I log `this.state` in the handler, and also `e.target.value`, `this.state.email` is always one character behind `e.target.value` (`budget` is another field...).

[image]

Is this normal? How can I fix it?

Comment: Where you are doing console.log? You should always do logging within callback method of setState.

Comment: where you log that values?

Answer (score 3):

`setState` is asynchronous, if you want to log what you just set in the state you need to pass a callback as second argument of the setState:

```
this.setState({somestate: somedata}, () => console.log(this.state.somestate))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your setState mutation could not be gotten immediately, so you could add a callback to get the new values applied :

```
handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    }, ()=>{
        console.log(this.state) //logs the new values
     })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not setting state in onChange event, since every keypress, you will call setState which can be on some older browsers really bad for performance. Instead you can use lodash's debounce in order to setState some time after last keypress.

```
handleChange = debounce(e => this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    }))

<Form.Control id="user_email" required type="email" onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)} name="email"/>
```